# compare array in bash

Tags: bash, array

**Question**: what does this line do? Can someone please explain?

```
 if [ $((${array[$i]}+1)) -ne ${array[$(($i + 1))]} ] ;then foo; fi
```

Comment: same as `if ((array[i] + 1 != array[i+1])); then foo; fi` (as long as `$i` and `array[i+1]` contain decimal integers).

Comment: It produces the value at position `[$i]` in `$array`, adds one to it  - inside an arithmetic context, then returns (via command substitution) that as the LHS operand to the `-ne` conditional operator, then evaluates the RHS operand,  `$(($i + 1))` is variable `$i + 1` then the result of this arithmetic operation is used as the key/position in the array  `${array[]}` - if the LHS and the RHS results are `-ne` "not equal` the `then` block runs

Comment: And also the same as `if [[ array[i]+1 -ne array[i+1] ]] ;then foo; fi` as both sides of an integer operator are processed as arithmetic expansions. In math: test for `A[i]+1 = A[i+1]`. Or, in words: is the next array element the consecutive numeric value of the present one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[ ... -ne ... ]` - [test for inequality](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test)
`$(( ... + 1))` - add one, [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)
`${array[$i]}` - reference to element `$i` of an [array variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)

Or in other words the test is `A[i] + 1 != A[i + 1]`